# iOS auto layout centering view with leading and tailing margin issue

Tags: ios, autolayout

I have a subview that contains UIImageView and label where label can be changed dynamically. I set this subview on storyboard with auto layout align vertical center and top/bottom space. So when its label get changed, margin between image and label remains same and subview maintains its align to vertical center as it grows horizontally. But I also want to this subview not to change its width when it hits certain margin (leading and tailing space) respective to its superview. I tried to add auto layout programatically once it reaches to certain point but removing its layout once its get shirked didn't work (i.e. label didn't get change its width even though I called `[label sizeToFit]`). One thing that came up on my mind was set leading and tailing layout on storyboard and change its constant value properly as label size changes. I would like to know if there is better solution to solve this layout issue. Thanks

Comment: Nope. I already achieved that part. The problem of that layout is UIView can grow horizontally over its superview.

Comment: if you want subbiew not to change its width, then set constraint for width

Comment: then layout of image and label is not gonna showed like the link you provided